# Create excel document programmatically in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010

Does the Word Automation Service or Excel Services contains API that allow us to create office document specifically in my case, an Excel document ?.

I need to create an Excel pro grammatically. I know it can be done using the [COM interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I would like to know if there are any "SharePoint Ways" to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

[Open XML API/SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) is the answer to your question..

Have a look at :

[Creating and Publishing Excel 2010 Documents with Custom SharePoint 2010 Workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg317441%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
[OpenXML Excel Generation - CodePlex](http://openxmlexcel.codeplex.com/)
[Writing data into excel document using openxml](http://www.prowareness.com/blog/writing-data-into-excel-document-using-openxml/)

And you can find many others if you search for it..

[Download Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=30425)

Comment: Salam, Thanks. I've already went through that materials. As I said in my question, I'm looking for "SharePoint Ways". I was hoping the word automation services or Excel Services or any other ootb SharePoint API is available for me to accomplish my task. Thanks

Comment: I didn't Open XML in your reference.. :) lets wait for other answers!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with SharePoint programmatically, your best bet is to use the template of the document library, as that's the only way I know of to "create" a document. Essentially this code will pull from the Document Template of the SharePoint library. You, of course, need to have an Excel document as a template of the document library already in place.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sharepointsite"))
         {
            using (SPWeb myWeb = site.OpenWeb())
            {
               SPDocumentLibrary myLib = myWeb.Lists["Library Name"];
               SPFolder myFolder = myLib.RootFolder;
               SPFile myFile = myWeb.GetFile(myDocLib.DocumentTemplateUrl);
               myFolder.Files.Add("File name", myFile.OpenBinary(), true);
             }
          }
```

I think with this code and the OpenXML API that Arsalan Adam Khatri posted, you should be able to do what you want to with SharePoint programmatically.